# Charset in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

$.ajax (javascript) send bad charset on page. Page charset is ISO-8859-2 and it's permanent. $.ajax ignore xhr request. I need **ěščřžýáíé** result instead *ÄĹĄÄĹĹžĂ˝ĂĄĂ­ĂŠ*

unescape, escape, encodeURIComponent(), decodeURIComponent() not working well

code:

```
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://url/',
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-2',
                        beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
                            jqXHR.overrideMimeType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-2;");
                        },
                        data: { textarea:textarea }
                    });
```

Comment: Does your server's response send the correct response header charset as well? You can check in Chrome's inspector in the Network tab, for example.

Comment: Request header in Network tab is right, as I define in ajax. Wierd.

Comment: What is the `charset` for the page? What is in the variable `textarea`? If this is text coming from an actual `textarea` element, it will inherit the charset of the document; see the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25665073/how-can-i-show-following-text-in-html-textarea) for some workarounds.

Comment: Charset page is iso-8859-2. HTML code text input: <input type="text" name="textarea" id="msg" value="">  I read some answers in your link, but accept-charset not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the content type as follows:

```
contentType:"application/x-javascript; charset:ISO-8859-1"
```

**UPDATE**
contentType is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; charset=utf-8 is a common one, as is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8, which is the default. What we are trying to do here is setting the content type to ISO-8859-1